# WebView's loadUrl("javascript:...") not working

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am playing with Android's WebView: I have a sample text "asdf" which shall be dyed when the user clicks on a button (red, green or blue). To make things a little bit more complicated, the WebView first tells the Java code to trigger the color change and then from within Java the WebView is changed:

```java
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }

        final WebAppInterface webAppInterface = new WebAppInterface(this, myWebView);
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(webAppInterface, "Android");
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }
}
```

This is the interface:

```
public class WebAppInterface {

    Context context;
    WebView webView;

    WebAppInterface(Context context, WebView webView) {
        this.context = context;
        this.webView = webView;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void dye(String color) {
        switch (color) {
            case "red":
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:dyeRed()");
                break;
            case "green":
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:dyeGreen()");
                break;
            case "blue":
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:dyeBlue()");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

In my html file there are 3 buttons like this one:

```xml
<button onClick="callDyeRed()">
    RED
</button>
```

And inside a javascript file that gets successfully loaded I have functions like these:

```js
function callDyeRed() {
  Android.dye("red");
}
function dyeRed() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color = 'red';
}
```

When I click on the button I see that inside WebAppInterface the line `webView.loadUrl("javascript:dyeRed()")` is executed. Thus, the js->Java communication works. However, the opposite is not true: Javascript code is not executed afterwards.

What am I missing here?

If I change the color from within a WebViewClient, the communication works:

```java
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:dyeGreen()");
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The object that is bound to the JavaScript runs in another thread('JavaBridge') and not in the thread ('Looper') in which it was constructed .
All WebView methods must be called on the same thread.So you can't call loadUrl method in the newly created  thread.

Possible workaround:

Webappinterface.java

```
class WebAppInterface {  

    Context context;
    WebView webView;

    WebAppInterface(Context context, WebView webView) {
        this.context = context;
        this.webView = webView;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String dye(String color) {
        switch (color) {
            case "red":
                return "dyeRed";
            case "green":
                return "dyeGreen";
            case "blue":
                return "dyeBlue";
            default:
                return "alert";

        }
    }
}
```

script.js

```
function callDyeRed() {
  window[Android.dye("red")]();
}
function dyeRed() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```